# How do you use a variable value to refer to another variable or object (i.e. EVAL in other languages)

Tags: c#, eval

Can I use a variable value as a reference in C# ? Consider the code below where 'myPointer' string holds the name of the variable I wish to output to the console... how can I do this ?  As an extension to this I also wish to use the same approach to be able to reference multiple objects using a list of names in a dictionary - possible ?

```
string strVar1 = "Hello World";

string strVar2 = "Goodbye World";

int i = 1;

string myPointer = eval("strVar"+i);   // there is no 'eval' in C#...

Console.WriteLine(myPointer);     // I want to display the value of strVar1
```

Comment: There is no direct equivalent. A "workaround" would be to have a `Dictionary<string, string>` where your "variable names" would be the keys

Comment: You could try to write dynamic functions directly in MSIL, use Roslyn complier libraries or work with Expressions, but this would be difficult to do. Please write in the question why are you trying to achieve this `eval` functionality as this smells like XY question (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: You shouldn't try to solve your problem with "eval" like methods. To [quote Rasmus Lerdorf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php#44008): "If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the
wrong question."

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps explain what issue you are actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything similar to 'eval' in c#, but you can use reflection to create types or get properties by name.

So if you have something like this:

```
class MyCLass
{
string strVar1 ;
string strVar2 ;
}
```

First, get your type name by adding 1 to its name:
    `string typeName = "strVar" + "1";`

Then you need to get property from class:

```
var myPropertyType = Typeof(MyClass).GetProperty(typeName);
```

After you can get the value of strvar1 by using the GetValue method:

```
var myValue = myPropertyType.GetValue(instance);
```

Where instance is your MyCLass's instance;

For more info read about [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection)

P.S. Also. there are some NuGet packages for "Eval", but I don't know if they have the functionality you need.